# grant particular table access to role in Snowflake

Tags: permissions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, roles, sql-grant

I have created a new table called `db.public.newTable`.
Now I need to give this table access to the role developer in Snowflake. What will the correct query grant this table access to the role developer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to grant all privileges you can do it like this:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLE db.public.newTable TO ROLE developer;
```

This is well documented [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/grant-privilege).